# Simulate latency and timeout between two microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul

Let's say you have microservice A that call's microservice B APIs.
I want to simulate latency and timeouts of B's APIs without touching the code of either A or B.

What I need is basically a third component, in the middle, that slows down A's invocation.

I was thinking about Zuul project, where I intercept A calls, and slow down (or simulate timeouts) responses with some logic.

Do you have a better solution?

Just for the record, this is needed only in test environment to check how A and B behave in this kind of situation.